# Entity framework and pure POCO update

Tags: entity-framework

How do I do an update on a pure POCO object using entity framework 4?

Lets say I change the person's first name and call the repository in this manner:

```
    public User Update(User user)
    {
        //User originalUser = GetUser(user.UserId);

        //Is there a way to update the values that are only changed?

        context.Users.Attach(user);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
        return user;
    }
```

I dont want null values to update the database to null. For eg. Suppose I have `LastName` as a property but when passing the object to the update function, it was null. Am I going to have to get the originalUser and then update each property accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

```
       "update each property accordingly?"
```

No, you can use,

```
       context.ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(newItem, out entity);

      // this will gives you the entity present in db and after that I suggest to write your code to change the state and save.
```

Also suggest you to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456854%28VS.100%29.aspx)
for more info on tracking changes in [POCO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/10/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-3-change-tracking-with-poco.aspx) entities