# jqGrid ASP.NET MVC3 + EF: Which is the best method to implement search?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, search, jqgrid

I'm still trying to implement research in jqGrid + MVC3, so far without success.

Meanwhile someone could solve me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027150/jqgrid-asp-net-4-mvc-how-to-make-search-implementation-on-a-dbcontext-reposit), **I was wondering what was in your opinion between these two articles the best search implementation and whether there are valid alternatives**:

1. [Using jqGrid’s search toolbar with multiple filters in ASP.NET MVC by Ilya Builuk](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58357/Using-jqGrid-s-search-toolbar-with-multiple-filter)
2. [jqGridDemo by @Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/1129461)
   Personally I feel the second solution more elegant and complete, but I'm still having problems. Moreover, in its code is used JavaScriptSerializer and I read in [this](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/14/38200/) blog that "The JavaScriptSerializer type was marked as obsolete prior to .NET Framework 3.5 SP1"...and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536359/why-microsoft-made-javascriptserializer-obsolete-prior-to-net-3-5-sp1-and-again) discussion get me more confused about this...

Personally, I am still having a problem with the **ObjectQuery** because I calculated properties of the entities, so they do no reside into the dataset ...

Thank you and I apologize if my questions can be trivial to most, but I am just a beginner...and I'm trying to learn...THX